TypeScript errors while upgrading Angular version to 14
I am upgrading an Angular project from version 10 to 17. During the transition from Angular 10 to Angular 14, I encountered several errors Like in the following function:
addPropertyDetails() {
  let form = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    plot: this._form.addDropDownFormGroup(),
    property: this._form.addDropDownFormGroup(),
    type: [''],
    isAllChecked: [false],
    validFrom: [''],
    validTo: [''],
    totalValue: [''],
    totalConsumption: [''],
    units: this.fb.array([])
  });

  form.valueChanges.subscribe(response => {
    let total = 0;
    let consumptionTotal = 0;
    let minDate: any = "";
    let maxDate: any = "";

    (form.get('units').value as any[]).forEach(elem => {
      if (elem.isChecked) {
        total += (parseFloat(elem.value)) ? parseFloat(elem.value) : 0;
        consumptionTotal += (parseFloat(elem.totalCalculation)) ? parseFloat(elem.totalCalculation) : 0;
      }

      if (!this._serv.checkForNull(elem.validFrom)) {
        let elemDate = new Date(elem.validFrom);
        if (minDate == "") {
          minDate = elemDate;
        } else if (minDate > elemDate) {
          minDate = elemDate;
        }
      }

      if (!this._serv.checkForNull(elem.validTo)) {
        let elemDate = new Date(elem.validTo);
        if (maxDate == "") {
          maxDate = elemDate;
        } else if (maxDate < elemDate) {
          maxDate = elemDate;
        }
      }
    });

    form.get('totalValue').setValue(total, { emitEvent: false });
    form.get('totalConsumption').setValue(consumptionTotal, { emitEvent: false });
    form.get('validFrom').setValue(minDate, { emitEvent: false });
    form.get('validTo').setValue(maxDate, { emitEvent: false });
  });

  return form;
}

I am encountering the following TypeScript errors:

Property 'isChecked' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
Property 'totalCalculation' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
Property 'validTo' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

I believe these errors are due to the stricter type checking in newer Angular versions. How can I resolve these issues?

It looks like you did not use the ng update schematics. Angular 14 introduced strictly typed forms. With the schematics, you code will be automatically migrated to use the previous non-type-safe implementation.

I have done ng update

We can define an interface for Unit, which will be set to the form array.
Then I use !. to make TypeScript know that the condition will not be null: form.get('totalValue')!.setValue(total, { emitEvent: false })
I have added the details on the comments for you to reference:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

export interface Unit { // create an interface for unit
  isChecked: boolean;
  value: string;
  totalCalculation: string;
  validFrom: Date;
  validTo: Date;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  form = new FormGroup({});
  _form = {
    addDropDownFormGroup: () => {},
  };
  _serv = {
    checkForNull: (test: any) => false,
  };

  addPropertyDetails() {
    let form = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      plot: this._form.addDropDownFormGroup(),
      property: this._form.addDropDownFormGroup(),
      type: [''],
      isAllChecked: [false],
      validFrom: [''],
      validTo: [''],
      totalValue: [0], // change type to number since we are assigning as number, I changed '' to 0, so type is inferred as number
      totalConsumption: [0], // change type to number since we are assigning as number, I changed '' to 0, so type is inferred as number
      units: this.fb.array<Unit>([]), // set the form array type to Unit
    });

    form.valueChanges.subscribe((response) => {
      let total = 0;
      let consumptionTotal = 0;
      let minDate: any = '';
      let maxDate: any = '';
      const unitsValue = form.get('units')!.value; // first get the value
      if (unitsValue) { // null check it so that values are present
        unitsValue.forEach((elem: Unit | null) => {
          if (elem) { // null check it so that values are present and type is unit!
            if (elem.isChecked) {
              total += parseFloat(elem.value) ? parseFloat(elem.value) : 0;
              consumptionTotal += parseFloat(elem.totalCalculation)
                ? parseFloat(elem.totalCalculation)
                : 0;
            }

            if (!this._serv.checkForNull(elem.validFrom)) {
              let elemDate = new Date(elem.validFrom);
              if (minDate == '') {
                minDate = elemDate;
              } else if (minDate > elemDate) {
                minDate = elemDate;
              }
            }

            if (!this._serv.checkForNull(elem.validTo)) {
              let elemDate = new Date(elem.validTo);
              if (maxDate == '') {
                maxDate = elemDate;
              } else if (maxDate < elemDate) {
                maxDate = elemDate;
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }

      form.get('totalValue')!.setValue(total, { emitEvent: false });
      form
        .get('totalConsumption')!
        .setValue(consumptionTotal, { emitEvent: false });
      form.get('validFrom')!.setValue(minDate, { emitEvent: false });
      form.get('validTo')!.setValue(maxDate, { emitEvent: false });
    });

    return form;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz with no errors
